# bootstrap menu not hiding after click the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the website [here](http://clickdesti.netne.net/)

When we view it minimized mode, the menu toggles ON after clicking the button, but when we click the button gain, it does not toggle off?

How to make this work ?

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
      <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Click<span>Desti</span></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_nav">
            <li><a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><b>Show Categories</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>               
            <li><a href="#contact">Contacts</a></li>                           
        </ul>           
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>     
    </nav>
```

Comment: There is a problem in your javascript code. I've used $('.navbar-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $('#navbar').slideToggle();
}); in the console and it worked. You should start from there.

Comment: it works, but when the side menu is hidden, it doesnt work ..any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: The responsive navbar requires the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Remove `role="navigation"` from your parent `nav.navbar`. That is only required if you use a `<div>` tag.

Comment: @AkashK I really cannot understand what u mean to say ? can you explain a bit ?

Comment: There's an extra javascript Plugin which is required for Responsive Collapsible menu to work as mentioned in docs. Include that file and remove `role` attribute from the `nav.navbar` element. Maybe that'll help